# how to calculate $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} |\sin(x)|e^{-inx} \mathrm{d}x$

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-integration

i have a calculating question
i want to calculate this integral
$$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} |\sin(x)|e^{-inx} \mathrm{d}x$$
i tried to use integration by parts but it just made it more complicated.
i already have the answer (USING MAPLE)

but i would appreciate if someone could take the time to explain the steps to me.
[image]

Comment: Get rid of the absolute values by cutting the integral in half : from $-\pi$ to $0$ and from $0$ to $\pi$. Then, write $\sin(x)$ as $Im(e^{ix})$.

Answer (score 1):

Hints: $e^{inx} =\cos (nx)+i \sin (nx)$. The integral of $|\sin x| \sin (nx)$ is $0$ because the function is odd. Also, $$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} |\sin x| \cos(nx )\mathrm{d}x =2 \int_{0}^{\pi} |\sin x| \cos(nx )\mathrm{d}x$$ Note that absolute value sign can now be dropped.  To evaluate this use the formula $$\sin A \cos B=\frac 1  2\left( \sin (A+B)+\sin (A-B)\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:$$\int_{-\pi}^\pi|\sin(x)|e^{-nix}\,\mathrm d x=2\int_0^\pi \sin(x)e^{-inx}\,\mathrm dx.$$

Use the fact that $\sin(x)=\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}$, and conclude.

Answer (score 0):

**By parts:**

We first need to get rid of the absolute value because it is not differentiable. As noted by others, exploiting parity we have

$$\int_{-\pi}^\pi|\sin x|e^{-inx}dx=2\int_0^\pi\sin x\,e^{-inx}dx.$$

Then

$$I:=\int_0^\pi\sin x\,e^{-inx}dx=\frac{i}n\left.\sin x\,e^{-inx}\right|_0^\pi-\frac{i}n\int_0^\pi\cos x\,e^{-inx}dx
\\=-\frac{i}n\int_0^\pi\cos x\,e^{-inx}dx$$

and

$$\int_0^\pi\cos x\,e^{-inx}dx
=-\frac{i}n\left.\cos x\,e^{-inx}\right|_0^\pi+\frac{i}n\int_0^\pi\sin x\,e^{-inx}dx
\\=-i\frac{e^{-in\pi}+1}n+\frac{i}nI.$$

Finally,

$$\left(1-\frac1{n^2}\right)I=-\frac{e^{-in\pi}+1}{n^2}.$$

[Typos not excluded.]

Comment: What happened to that 2 (which should be multipled in the second line) ?

Comment: @Negar: I cleaned the extra one.

Comment: I don’t get it . Why did you do that ? Can you please add some notes in your answer so i can follow ? (Thank you in advance)

Comment: @Negar: there were incoherent edits, sorry.